# How do I use startsWith with a form submission when filtering array data from an API in React?

Tags: reactjs, user-input

Sorry for the noob question, just starting out in React. So my page accesses a list of counties formatted as an Array from an API using this component:

```
class FetchRandomCounty extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    county: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/counties";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ county: data, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.county ? (
          <div> loading... </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div>
              {" "}
              {this.state.county
                .filter((item) => item.startsWith("J"))
                .map((item) => (
                  <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                ))}{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The fetched data is an Array that looks like this:

```
["Aransas", "Austin", "Bastrop", "Bee", "Brazoria", "Burleson", "Caldwell", "Calhoun", "Chambers", "Colorado", "Comal", "De Witt", "Fayette", "Fort Bend", "Galveston", "Goliad", "Gonzales", "Grimes", "Guadalupe", "Hardin", "Harris", "Jackson", "Jasper", "Jefferson", "Jim Wells"]
```

And the output currently is this:

- Jackson
- Jasper
- Jefferson
- Jim Wells

How do I prompt the user to enter a letter and filter the array to only display data that starts with that letter? Right now I am using `item.startsWith('J'))` and would like to make it respond to user input. This is my User input component:

```
class LetterForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("A letter was submitted: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          StartsWith:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep `FetchRandomCounty` and `LetterForm` as separate components, you could control the selected letter with a prop to `FetchRandomCounty` and control it from the parent, and introduce a `onChange` callback prop for `LetterForm` that you use to change the stored selected letter in the parent.

**Example**

```js
const data = [
  "Aransas",
  "Austin",
  "Bastrop",
  "Bee",
  "Brazoria",
  "Burleson",
  "Caldwell",
  "Calhoun",
  "Chambers",
  "Colorado",
  "Comal",
  "De Witt",
  "Fayette",
  "Fort Bend",
  "Galveston",
  "Goliad",
  "Gonzales",
  "Grimes",
  "Guadalupe",
  "Hardin",
  "Harris",
  "Jackson",
  "Jasper",
  "Jefferson",
  "Jim Wells"
];

class FetchRandomCounty extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    county: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/counties";
    // const response = await fetch(url);
    // const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ county: data, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, county } = this.state;
    const selectedLetter = this.props.selectedLetter.toLowerCase();

    return (
      <div>
        {loading || !county ? (
          <div> loading... </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <div>
              {county
                .filter((item) => item.toLowerCase().startsWith(selectedLetter))
                .map((item) => (
                  <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class LetterForm extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "" };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value.slice(0, 1) });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onChange(this.state.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          StartsWith:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = { selectedLetter: "J" };

  updateLetter = (selectedLetter) => {
    this.setState({ selectedLetter });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FetchRandomCounty selectedLetter={this.state.selectedLetter} />
        <LetterForm onChange={this.updateLetter} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```